# Sum values on the same day and when values are displayed in consecutive rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to know how to calculate the sum of values which satisfy the condition when they are on the same day and also in consecutive rows:

| Date | Condition | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02 | True | 100 |
| 2022-01-02 | False | 50 |
| 2022-01-02 | True | 100 |
| 2022-01-03 | True | 300 |
| 2022-01-03 | False | 50 |
| 2022-01-03 | True | 300 |
| 2022-01-04 | True | 100 |
| 2022-02-01 | True | 100 |
| 2022-02-19 | False | 10 |
| 2022-02-20 | True | 500 |
| 2022-03-09 | False | 90 |
| 2022-03-10 | True | 10 |
| 2022-03-10 | True | 10 |

The expected output is the following:

| header 1 | Condition | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02 | True | 1000 |
| 2022-01-02 | False | 50 |
| 2022-01-02 | True | 1000 |
| 2022-01-03 | True | 1000 |
| 2022-01-03 | False | 50 |
| 2022-01-03 | True | 1000 |
| 2022-01-04 | True | 1000 |
| 2022-02-01 | True | 1000 |
| 2022-02-19 | False | 10 |
| 2022-02-20 | True | 500 |
| 2022-03-09 | False | 90 |
| 2022-03-10 | True | 20 |
| 2022-03-10 | True | 20 |

Comment: Why does `2022-02-01` get `1000` in the output? And should the other `1000` not be `900` if you only want the `True` Condition rows?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by **identical** days in successive rows, compare the successive rows and use [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)+[`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to generate a grouper, then use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
group = df[['Date', 'Condition']].ne(df[['Date', 'Condition']].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()

out = df.assign(Value=df.groupby(group)['Value'].transform('sum'))
```

Output:

```
          Date  Condition  Value
0   2022-01-02       True    100
1   2022-01-02      False     50
2   2022-01-02       True    100
3   2022-01-03       True    300
4   2022-01-03      False     50
5   2022-01-03       True    300
6   2022-01-04       True    100
7   2022-02-01       True    100
8   2022-02-19      False     10
9   2022-02-20       True    500
10  2022-03-09      False     90
11  2022-03-10       True     20
12  2022-03-10       True     20
```

If you want to group by **successive days** of the matching condition:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

group = (df.sort_values(by=['Condition', 'Date'])
           .groupby('Condition')['Date']
           .diff().gt('1D').cumsum()
         )

out = df.assign(Value=df.groupby([group, 'Condition'])['Value'].transform('sum'))
```

Output:

```
         Date  Condition  Value
0  2022-01-02       True    900
1  2022-01-02      False    100
2  2022-01-02       True    900
3  2022-01-03       True    900
4  2022-01-03      False    100
5  2022-01-03       True    900
6  2022-01-04       True    900
7  2022-02-01       True    100
8  2022-02-19      False     10
9  2022-02-20       True    500
10 2022-03-09      False     90
11 2022-03-10       True     20
12 2022-03-10       True     20
```

Comment: Hey Mozway. Hope you're great. I'm curious to know how were you able to answer 10k questions in just 2 years?! What's your secret? Do you just stay all day on SO, or simply automate some of your answers, or your account is managed by multiple persons? Just how you do it. Thanks

Comment: I am willing to pay 30$ in your BuyMeACoffee account but I'm not sure whether this is a bot account or not

Comment: @Yves haha, thanks for the offer, no I'm not a bot, just a (busy) human being @$&! \*\*fatal error\*\* rebooting…